# What is this agglomeration of pink cells I found attached to a stone?

Tags: species-identification, invertebrates, molluscs, gastropod

Photo taken in a garden in Singapore. The organism is attached to a stone, close to water. Many of these were there.

Size approx 3cm.

The shell of this eggs is very soft. When touched, a pink colored liquid drops out.
[image: Photo taken in a garden in Singapore. Size approx 3cm.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are Apple snail's eggs; check the picture:

Check [this](https://www.seriouslyfish.com/apple-snails-eggs-contain-unique-poison/).

[image: snail eggs]

Answer (score 4):

This could very well be the eggs from an apple snail (family [Ampullariidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampullariidae)).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampullariidae#Ecology)

> Several apple snail genera (Pomacea, Pila and Asolene/Pomella) **deposit eggs above the waterline in calcareous clutches**. This remarkable strategy of aquatic snails protects the eggs against predation by fish and other aquatic inhabitants.

If these are in fact the eggs from an apple snail, then the parent is likely in the genus *Pila* since this is the only major genus found in Asia [[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampullariidae#Distribution)].

You can see a timelapse video of a snail laying eggs [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfP0XKlNy20) and a short gif below:

[image]

<sup>Source: [gfycat](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/AlarmedVigilantBlackbuck-size_restricted.gif)</sup>

See [applesnail.net](https://www.applesnail.net/content/pila.htm) for more info.