# What made this, is it an egg sac?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]Found this "egg ball" on a gate near a greenbelt north of Seattle, WA. From other posts here, it looks similar to snail eggs, but they do not have the webbing. Two days later I went back out to measure it, but it was gone. Maybe hatched or eaten?

[image]s://i.stack.imgur.com/tj6gT.jpg

Comment: similar: [What is this agglomeration of pink cells I found attached to a stone?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/82344/16866)